# Image Description on Hover Image Link in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: html, sharepoint

I have a webpage which contains 12 pictures. I want when I hover my mouse over each picture then I should get the information about the pictures. I am very new to SharePoint 2013 and I have no idea how to implement this. Please help.

Comment: in order to get help faster, please consider making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example

Answer (score 0):

If you want quite a fancy looking hover effect, than you can do it using jquery and xslt. 
I assume you have a picture library. In picture library add the description column. Now render your list using custom xslt and apply jquery plugin to have the hover effect
http://www.designrazzi.net/2014/free-image-hover-effects/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

[jQuery Capty](http://www.wbotelhos.com/capty/)